# params object[] method parameters boxed?

Tags: c#, object, casting, parameters, boxing

Ok, so when I have a method that looks like

```
getPacket(params object[] inputs)
{

 }
```

Is the inputs array an array of boxed variables or is it simply just an array of the original types (im sending multiple different types tho, eg. short, int, bool)

If they are boxed can you do run-time unboxing to the original type without knowing the original type?

If they aren't boxed, how can I tell whether it's an int, short, bool etc. as I want to be able to make a single method that puts together a byte array from a whole stack of different types.

Another question, are the objects in the array in the same order as they were passed in the method invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects in the array will be in the same order that they were passed to the method and they will be boxed if the source parameter is a value type.

You can use the `is` keyword to check the underlying type of each object and act accordingly, for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Receive(1, true);
}

static void Receive(params object[] values)
{
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        if (v is int)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (v is bool)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the order and boxing, can I use `.getType()` (I know it gets the source type from the boxed object) to cast? Like: `(inputs[0].getType())inputs[0]` ???

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You could use `Convert.ChangeType` to dynamically convert to a type, but I don't believe it will be useful for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks :) how fast is the `if`s tho... I have the rest of my packet handling down to under 0.5ms so a whole stack of if( ? is  ? ) may slow it down? Or not?

Comment: I would say that compared to the required boxing/unboxing the if statements impact will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array of objects, then yes, if for example you put integers in the array, they will be boxed. I dont know of any unboxing methods without knowing the actual types involved, so you will have to cast the items in the array to whatever value they actually represent.

Comment: What if I don't know? I know for example I can try cast an int to short and it won't work, so I know it's an int... but a short can be casted to an int... Can I do: `(inputs[0].getType())inputs[0]`?